# XSL-FO leader wrapping

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, antenna-house

I have a list of data with a dotted leader separating text aligned to the left and to the right.  I'm using the following XSL-FO to achieve this.

```
<fo:block text-align-last="justify">
    <xsl:value-of select="left-text"/>
    <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="right-text"/>
</fo:block>
```

> ```
> Some text on the left............................some text on the right
> ```

This works perfectly when the text all fits onto one line.  The issue I'm having is correctly handling how the text on the right wraps onto a new line.  I have a specific requirement for it to be formatted with the wrapped text staying aligned to the right as below:

> ```
> Some text on the left.................a long piece of text on the right 
>                                                        that has wrapped
> ```

I tried to achieve this with leaders and tables but to no avail.  I'm using the Antenna House formatter. Any advice is very welcome.
Thanks for you help.

Comment: can you set the whole `fo:block` to be right-aligned?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. It made no difference to the formatting.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: 1) You should show your table test and 2) in the picture you depict, you have some formatting rule you have not specified. You have actually drawn a picture that implies you have some width that you wish the leader to never be shorter than. What I mean by that, is that more of the text you show would fit in the line with less dots. What are the rules ... ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this as inspiration and set your own rules:

```
       <fo:block text-align="justify" text-align-last="right">
           <fo:inline>Some text on the left</fo:inline>
           <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" leader-length.minimum="2in" leader-length.optimum="2in" leader-length.maximum="3in"/>
           <fo:inline>a long piece of text on the right that has wrapped</fo:inline>
       </fo:block>
        <fo:block text-align="justify" text-align-last="right">
           <fo:inline>Some text</fo:inline>
           <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" leader-length.minimum="2in" leader-length.optimum="2in" leader-length.maximum="3in"/>
           <fo:inline>a long piece of text on the right that has wrapped and is even longer</fo:inline>
       </fo:block>
```

The only things you will not be able to stop is a right hand line so long that it comes underneath the dots, but you have not specified that as a requirement. If that is, I am afraid there is no solution for that. Also if a line is too short, it would be right aligned. You have to use the min/max values to only force a wrap.

If you know the font size you could count the characters in the left/right elements and then call your template or this sample depending on the total characters.

[image: Result of this FO]

And for the count, you can do something like this template where the "50" characters you can adjust with the leader-length to get the correct results.

```
<xsl:template name="processitem">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length(left) + string-length(right) > 50">
            <fo:block text-align="justify" text-align-last="right">
                <fo:inline><xsl:value-of select="left"/></fo:inline>
                <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" leader-length.minimum="2in" leader-length.optimum="2in" leader-length.maximum="4in"/>
                <fo:inline><xsl:value-of select="right"/></fo:inline>
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <fo:block text-align-last="justify">
                <fo:inline><xsl:value-of select="left"/></fo:inline>
                <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/>
                <fo:inline><xsl:value-of select="right"/></fo:inline>
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

With some sample data, I got this to render:

[image: Using Template Above with Sample Data]

Comment: Thank you, this has been a really big help.  As you suggested I just needed to tweak the max character length value and I got it working with my stylesheet.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `fo:inline-container` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_inline-container) and the `max-width` property (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#max-width) to limit the width of any long text on the right.

This example uses the `axf:text-align-first="justify"` extension (see https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf66/ahf-ext.html#axf.text-align-first) to justify the first line.  You could instead use the `axf:leader-expansion="force"` extension (see https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf66/ahf-ext.html#axf.leader-expansion).  Without either of those, I think that your only other alternative is to guesstimate the `leader-length.optimum` of the second `fo:leader`.

Note that the example below has no significant white-space characters between the two `fo:leader`.  This avoids a gap between the two leaders when they are formatted.

```
<fo:block text-align="justify">
  <fo:inline>Some text</fo:inline><fo:leader
  leader-pattern="dots" leader-length.optimum="100%"
  leader-alignment="end"
  /><fo:inline-container
  max-width="1.5in" text-align="right"
  axf:text-align-first="justify" >
          <fo:block><fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"
  leader-length.minimum="0" />a long piece of text on the right that has wrapped
and is even longer</fo:block>
  </fo:inline-container>
</fo:block>
```

[image: Example of multiple lines of right-justified text after a leader.]